# Phrase to mean "fully prepared"

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a phrase to mean that one is fully prepared for the task ahead.

I was originally thinking of "all the pieces are falling into position" but that implies things are presently coming together, not that they have already.

Comment: The task is in hand?

Comment: *Everything is set*!

Comment: Ready and waiting?

Comment: All set (to go) ( see comment by @Josh61)

Comment: "all the pieces are finally in position"

Comment: Why are these comments instead of answers?

Comment: If you want a phrase that means *fully prepared*, then "fully prepared" would seem to fit the bill. Is there some other requirement you need to satisfy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just fix the one you were leaning towards to begin with: All the pieces HAVE fallen into position.

Comment: Hmm I like the idea of modifying existing phrases subtly. I wasn't sure it would still be a well known phrase if it were modified even slightly but upon further reflection I think this would be acceptable. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**"We are *ready to rock and roll*,"** is a common phrase. (US)

Answer (score 6):

"I'm locked and loaded" is sometimes used in the US.

Answer (score 6):

[**Good to go**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+to+go)

> all ready to go; all checked and pronounced ready to go.
>
> ready for the situation

Answer (score 4):

What about this one:  *I am ready to go* ?

Answer (score 3):

- I'm all [geared up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/gear-up).

> gear up: to prepare yourself/somebody/something to do something

- I'm [hot to trot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hot#hot__47).

> *informal* Ready and eager to engage in an activity.

[Oxford]

Comment: You're also *locked and loaded*, of course. At least if you're a US action hero.

Comment: @DanBron: Of course :)

Comment: Hot to trot has a sexual connotation that ColdFusion might not want

Answer (score 2):

How about "I'm squared away"

def1 "to square the yards so as to sail before the wind"
def2 to square away "to put everything into readiness"

Answer (score 2):

My wife and I use the phrase "Ready to go?" and "Ready to go." so much that if our dog hears us say it he will get super excited.

Answer (score 1):

**I am good to go!**

In the US Military this expression is the response you can expect to the question, "Are you fully prepared for the mission at hand?"

Answer (score 0):

*I'm ready to rumble*, often used to excite the audience of a competition as it's about to begin.

*I'm set to jet*, particularly applicable when talking about being prepared for a journey, but can be used in pretty much any context to suggest preparations are complete.

*We're five by five* can be used to indicate readiness. It comes from radio communication jargon, where it's used to indicate signal quality is optimum and transmission can commence. It's a bit technical, but it works.

*Ready, Freddy!* is a popular silly option. It's silly because you're probably not telling it to someone named Freddy, you're just saying "Freddy" because it rhymes with "ready". If the person you're announcing it to is actually named Freddy, then it's still funny because the idiom is well-known so the situation is a humorous coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

"Primed" or "Fully primed" or more colloquially, "cooking on gas".

Answer (score 0):

You can say that someone is *ready for action*.

That is a pretty common idiomatic expression.